# trying out unix network programming

Tags: unix-socket

I have been studying unix network programming and have been running servers on 127.0.0.1. But i want to try it on a bigger scale just to spice things up and also get more practical. So, i want host my server applications out on the net. I have heard that there are servers out there  which allow you to create an http page and upload it and then view it as an internet user. So, are there other such servers which sublet few ports so that people can run their applications on them.

**Note:** using my friends' computers as a remote device for server and then connecting to it is not feasible as they use Windows and i have to run unix server

**UPDATE:**
If my question was not clear, here is an another way i can put it in.

There are services running on ports of different hosts on the internet..like smtp server on port 25 at a particular ip...we can telnet to port 25 of that ip and communicate with that service...in the same way are there any sites which provide a particular port and an ip, so that i can upload my service's object file on that host by ftp, cause that service to run on my assigned port and then using my client on my computer connect to that service over the internet

Comment: You could run a Unix server as a virtual machine, using Xen, VMWare, or similar? But to be honest, I don't really understand your question...

Comment: @RB...i am sorry if i couldn't convey my doubts clearly...i will try again...there are services running on ports of different hosts on the internet..like smtp server on port 25 at a particular ip...we can telnet to port 25 of that ip and communicate with that service...in the same way are there any sites which provide a particular port and an ip, so that i can upload my service's object file on that host by ftp, cause that service to run on my assigned port and then using my client on my computer connect to that service over the internet